# What files should be included in the tessdata folder after training tesseract?

Tags: c#, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, tessnet2

I am using tesseract as the OCR engine for my ANPR application. I have trained tesseract 3.01v with the numberplate font. But I need to know:

1. Which files should be included in the tessdata folder?
2. Should I use the same tessdata folder where tesseract 3.01v is installed?
3. I have trained with tesseract 3.01v and I am using tessnet2 in my code so will it be a problem?

Following is the code that I tried it with but it keeps exiting from the DoOcr() method.

```
List<tessnet2.Word> ocrText = new List<tessnet2.Word>();
tessnet2.Tesseract ocr = new tessnet2.Tesseract();
ocr.Init(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata", "eng", true);
ocrText = ocr.DoOCR(bmpGrayScale, new Rectangle(rect.X, rect.Y, rect.Width, rect.Height));

foreach (tessnet2.Word word in ocrText)
Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", word.Confidence, word.Text);
```

Does anyone have an idea as to whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"3.01 is not backwards compatible with 2.04. The data files are different."

http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/ReadMe

For .NET library compatible with 3.01, look at the project at http://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/ or https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract-ocr-dotnet.

Comment: But what should I do then? can you please be a bit more specific?

Comment: If you train for 3.01, then you must use the resultant data with 3.0x engine.